# Why do I getting 'FileField' object has no attribute 'put'?

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs, mongoengine

Following http://mongoengine.org/docs/v0.4/guide/gridfs.html documentation about mongoengine FileField I did the following:

In my model

```
files = ListField(FileField())
```

In my test code

```
    # Create an entry 
    photo = FileField()
    f  = open('/home/foo/marmot.jpg', 'r')   
    photo.put(f, content_type='image/jpeg')
    entry.files = [photo,]
```

Trying to follow the doc, however i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bar/tests.py", line 76, in test_MongoDGACLogook_creation
    photo.put(f, content_type='image/jpeg')
AttributeError: 'FileField' object has no attribute 'put'
```

Am I missing something obvious ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    f = mongoengine.fields.GridFSProxy()
    to_read = open('/home/.../marmot.jpg', 'r')   
    f.put(to_read, filename=os.path.basename(to_read.name))
    to_read.close()
```

Comment: How is this answer putting FileFields into a ListField??

Answer (score 2):

This isn't obvious at all IMO, but if you look at the Mongoengine code you'll see that the `put` method is defined in the `GridFSProxy` class, which is accessed via a descriptor in `FileField` (the `__get__` and `__set__` methods).

Looking at the code and the examples in the docs, it appears the only way to access or use a `FileField` is through the descriptor....so, `collection.file_field`.

Given all this, I don't think it's possible to have a list of file fields using the Mongoengine API as it exists now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading multiples files and trying to save it a ListField(FileField())

```
<input type='file' name='myfiles' multiple="">

files = []
for f in request.FILES.getlist('myfiles'):
    mf = mongoengine.fields.GridFSProxy()
    mf.put(f, filename=f.name)
    files.append(mf)
entry.files = files
entry.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. As suggested by @KoppeKTop on GitHub in [this post](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/issues/86#issuecomment-90973990), I finally extended my model (`Pet`) using an EmbeddedDocument like this:

```
class OneImage(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    element = ImageField()

class Pet(mongoengine.Document):
    photos = EmbeddedDocumentListField(OneImage)
    # ...more fields... #
```

I can then add a new image using

```
    i = OneImage()
    i.element.put(form.photo.data.stream)
    entry.photos.append(i)
    entry.save()
```

This may not always be the best option, but personally I prefer it because I can work with models as usual without having to work with proxies. And I can also save other photo metadata in the future, if I need to.